# Como almacenar en una lista numeros ingresados por el usuario en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola no entiendo como puedo resolver esto ... "Escribir un programa que lea entre 10 a 20 números ingresados por el usuario, los
almacene en una lista y los muestre ordenados de mayor o menor. Debe recibir el ingreso
de números hasta que el usuario ingrese 0. Pero el 0 no se debe mostrar en pantalla"

```
lista=[]
valor=int(input("Ingrese valor (0 para finalizar): "))
while valor != 0:
    lista.append(valor)
    valor=int(input("Ingresar valor (0 para finalizar): "))

print("Tamaño de la lista: ")
print(valor)
```

He llegado a eso pero no se como imprimirlo de mayor a menor y como puedo almacenar todos los valores en una lista

Comment: Bienvenido Jose c: te dejan usar la función sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder a tu pregunta, ya tienes los elementos almacenados en la lista. Los has ido añadiendo tu mismo en la línea:

```
lista.append(valor)
```

Ya que ordenar e imprimir es lo que realmente te falta:

- Para ordenar la lista, utiliza el método `sort()`.
- Para imprimirla, pasale a `print()` la lista como tal.
- Para obtener su tamaño, utiliza la función `len()`.

En código, luciría algo como:

```
lista.sort()
print("Tamaño de la lista: ", len(lista))
print("Lista ordenada ")
print(lista)
```